# What is the proper procedure to rename columns in an MSSQL Database via VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am having an issue with renaming columns. My code is as follows:

```
Using m_cnInterval
    Using m_CMDInterval = New SqlCommand()
        m_CMDInterval.Connection = m_cnInterval
        m_CMDInterval.CommandText = "EXEC sp_rename '[" & strClassColumnName(intClassArrayPosition) & "]', '[" & strRenameClassColumn(intClassArrayPosition) & "]', 'COLUMN'"
        m_CMDInterval.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        m_CMDInterval.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

I am getting an error message as follows:

"Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (column) is wrong"

I think this error is related to the way I am using my single quotes and brackets. Is there another syntax when using variables for column names?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up using the following:

```
m_CMDInterval.CommandText = "EXEC sp_rename 'Interval.[" & strClassColumnName _
(intClassArrayPosition) & "]', '" & strRenameClassColumn(intClassArrayPosition) _
 & "', 'COLUMN'"
```

I needed to specify the table name with the column name. I used the brackets because the column name has a space in it. I did not have to use brackets on the column name that was renaming with, even though it does have a space in the name as well.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a qualified path to the table in the first argument. Try something like this:

```
m_CMDInterval.CommandText =
        String.Format("EXEC sp_rename '[{0}].[dbo].[{1}].[{2}]', '{3}', 'COLUMN'",
                      "databasename",
                      "tablename",
                      "old column name",
                      "new column name")
```

where you fill in the values with your variables.
The new name must not have brackets [] or they become part of the new name (at least that's what I've just seen when testing in SSMS).